# Focus / blur events on contenteditable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I'm trying to listen to focus / blur events on `span` with `contenteditable=true` attribute.**

So here's what I tried (jQuery) :

```
$('.editable').on('focus',function(){
    var that = $(this),
        defaultTxt = that.data('default');
    that.html('');
});
$('.editable').on('blur',function(){
    var that = $(this),
        defaultTxt = that.data('default');
    if(that.html() === ''){
        that.html(defaultTxt);
    }
});
```

But he doesn't seem to work, because **span doesn't handle focus / blur**. How can I achieve that anyway (IE8 support needed) ?

Comment: Why use a span? You could also try targeting the content editable section with attribute (`attr`)?

Comment: I need basic inline element ( = span). Yes I also could target content editable section with attribute ([contenteditable]), but that's not the point here.

Comment: $('.editable').on('mousedown' .... something i guess

Comment: I can use .on('click',...) or mousedown to emulate focus, but how can I detect blur in that way ?

Comment: You have to listen on all clicks on body and if mouse is hover the span. if not hover span then blur out of span

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this effect.

## Approach 1: `focusin` and `focusout`

```
$('.editable').on('focusin', function() {
    // your code here
});

$('.editable').on('focusout', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

`focusin` and `focusout` are like `focus` and `blur` events, but unlike the latter, they are fired on almost(?) every element, and also bubble. `focusin` and `focusout` are a part of DOM level 3 Specification.  Firefox 51 and older didn't support this due to a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687787), but Firefox 52 and above have full support.

## Approach 2: `click` and `focus`

This only works if you have other `focus`able elements around your span. What you do is basically use the `focus` event on any other element as a blur handler.

```
$('.editable').on('click', function() {
    // your code here
});

$('*').on('focus', function() {
    // handle blur here
    // your code here
});
```

I wouldn't recommend this approach in a large webapp, because browser performance will take a hit.

Comment: Mozilla implemented a fix for OP's linked bug in Firefox 52. Majority of Firefox users are on v52 or later, but there are still users on older versions (https://caniuse.com/usage-table).

Answer (score 3):

I have created a demo for you:

```js
$('.editable').bind('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('contentEditable',true);
});

$('.editable').bind('focus', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  //defaultTxt = that.data('default');
  that.html('');    
});

$('.editable').bind('blur', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var defaultTxt = that.data('default');
  if(that.html() === ''){
    that.html(defaultTxt);
  }    
});
```

```css
.editable{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="editable" data-default="default">Some text</span>
```

I have changed your code, take a look it. Also now it's keeping the old value when lost the focus if you don't type anything.

Comment: As you can see, it doesn't work properly : the first click on the span just add the contenteditable attribute (note : it's already set in the HTML), only the second one focus on the span. Thank you anyway for that.