# Make a p element both content editable and JQuery UI Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, contenteditable

Is it possible to make a `p` element both content editable AND JQuery UI Sortable?

In my simple example below, the `p` elements are sortable but you cannot edit their text. Is there anyway to overcome this?

*Note I have tried nesting `p`'s in containers so that the container is sortable and the `p` is editable but I still cannot edit the inner `p`.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".elements" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".elements"
 });
});
```

```css
p {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/js/visual-designer.min.js"></script>

<div class="elements">
 <p id="foo" contenteditable="true">Foo. Help! I can be sorted but cannot be edited.</p>
 
 <!-- Even if I nest p's in a container they still are not editable -->
 <div class="test-container">
  <p id="bar" contenteditable="true">Bar. Help! I can be sorted but cannot be edited.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to get some help from here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745046/7844349

Answer (score 2):

Through some random attempts at getting it to work, I found that setting focus on the element, and then moving the cursor to the end of the content editable (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3866442/5894241) by  [Nico Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140293/nico-burns)) is adequate to get the content editable working.

My guess is that the sortable prevents the content editable from getting focus because of some sort of `event.preventDefault` or `cancelBubble`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".elements").sortable({
    connectWith: ".elements"
  });

  $(".elements p").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).focus();
    setEndOfContenteditable(e.target);
  });
});

function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
  var range, selection;
  if (document.createRange) //Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
  {
    range = document.createRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
    range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
    range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
    selection = window.getSelection(); //get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
    selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any selections already made
    selection.addRange(range); //make the range you have just created the visible selection
  } else if (document.selection) //IE 8 and lower
  {
    range = document.body.createTextRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
    range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
    range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
    range.select(); //Select the range (make it the visible selection
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/js/visual-designer.min.js"></script>

<div class="elements">
  <p id="foo" contenteditable="true">Foo. Help! I can be sorted but cannot be edited.</p>

  <div>
    <p id="bar" contenteditable="true">Bar. Help! I can be sorted but cannot be edited.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not allowing the edition because Jquery is overwriting some event callback enabled by default in **contenteditable=true** elements.

You can try overwriting **focusin** and **focusout** events in order to allow that edition. Check how they are doing it in the link below:

[Focus / blur events on contenteditable elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556510/focus-blur-events-on-contenteditable-elements)

I hope it'll help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where when the element is clicked, the `p` tag is converted to an `input` tag, and when the focus is lost, its converted back to a `p` tag!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // How to associate a handle that sits outside the element to be dragged?
   $( ".elements" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".foo"
 });
  
  function focusout(){
    var val = $('input[contenteditable*="true"]').val();
    var replacement2 = $('<p contenteditable="true">'+val+'</p>');
    $('input[contenteditable*="true"]').replaceWith(replacement2);
    replacement2.on("click", clicked);
  }
  
  function clicked(){
    var replacement = $('<input contenteditable="true" value="'+this.innerHTML+'"/>');
    $(this).replaceWith(replacement);
    replacement.on("focusout", focusout);
    $('input[contenteditable*="true"]').focus();
  }
  
  $('p[contenteditable*="true"]').on("click", clicked);
  
});
```

```css
p {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="elements">
 <p id="foo" contenteditable="true">Foo. Help! I can be sorted but cannot be edited.</p>
 
 <!-- Even if I nest p's in a container they still are not editable -->
 <div class="test-container">
  <p id="bar" contenteditable="true">Bar. Help! I can be sorted but cannot be edited.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```